# Why does "read -t" block in scripts launched from xcodebuild?

Tags: macos, bash, xcodebuild

I have a script that creates a FIFO and launches a program that writes output to the FIFO. I then read and parse the output until the program exits.

```
MYFIFO=/tmp/myfifo.$$
mkfifo "$MYFIFO"
MYFD=3
eval "exec $MYFD<> $MYFIFO"
external_program >&"$MYFD" 2>&"$MYFD" &
EXT_PID=$!

while kill -0 "$EXT_PID" ; do
  read -t 1 LINE <&"$MYFD"
# Do stuff with $LINE
done
```

This works fine reading input while the program is still running, but it looks like the timeout to read is ignored, and read call hangs after the external program exits.

I've used read with a timeout successfully in other scripts, and a simple test script that leaves out the external program times out correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: It looks like `read -t` functions as expected when I run my script from the command line, but when I run it as part of an xcodebuild build process, the timeout does not function. What is different about these two environments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `-t` will work with redirection.

From the man page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html):

> -t timeout
>       Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line
>       of input is not read within timeout seconds. **This option has no
>       effect if read is not reading input from the *terminal* or a *pipe*.**

Comment: I am reading from a pipe -- mkfifo creates a pipe in the filesystem. I've used largely the same code before successfully, and am at a loss as to why it isn't working in this case.

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know. I don't have any experience with mkfifo, so I was unaware.